# Adding jars to Android Studio as Library, Error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, web-scraping, bots

I am trying to add Selenium to Android studio in order to automate a web form while the device is in standby mode. I keeping running into more and more errors. I added all of the .jars into the Lib file and added them as a library, then I ran into this problem. Please help me. Here is my gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mul.luke.selenium"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.9.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guava-23.6-jre.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.11.0-sources.jar')
    implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.11.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

The above will include all jars in the libs. Right?

You are trying to add the same library again with specific path as well.

```
implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar')
```

Exclude dependencies in packagingOptions,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mul.luke.selenium"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
     packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      }

}
```

Comment: Deleting all of the implementations still left me with the same error @Navarasu

Comment: Do you want those files while packaging?

Comment: Yeah I need them as a library. I don’t know if I need them when packaging.

Comment: Then adding packagingOptions will solve your issue. Can you check?. I have edited the answer